# How well do continuously differentiable functions behave from R^2 to R^2 ?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, real-analysis

The behaviour of complex smooth vs 1-dimensional real smooth functions is discussed in a [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3819/why-do-functions-in-complex-analysis-behave-so-well-as-opposed-to-functions-in).

In ["Complex Analysis as Catalyst"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703006) by Steven G. Krantz,  the Cauchy integral formula is generalized from holomorphic functions to continuously differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$:

$f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial \Omega} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z} d\zeta  - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \iint_\Omega  \frac{\partial f/\partial \overline{\zeta} }{\zeta-z} d\overline{\zeta} \wedge d\zeta  $

Does this integral formula imply any rigidity for functions that are only continuously differentiable ($C^1$) but 2-dimensional ?

Comment: That theorem of Krantz's is basically just a reformulation of Green's theorem.   The only hope you have for having "analytic-like rigidity" coming from Green's theorem would be to weaken your notion of "analytic-like" to the point that it has no resemblance to "analytic". 

Comment: What exactly do you mean by rigidity?